# target --> selector VS selector --> target

Tags: jquery

I ask this question only to better understand jQuery. I've noticed that some jQuery methods differ only in the order of the target and selector. Example:

```
$('img').replaceWith('<p>Hello</p>');    // target --> selector (or content)
$('<p>Hello</p>').replaceAll('img');     // selector --> target
```

But this seems to be the only way that they are completely reversible. Example:

```
$('img').replaceWith(Hello);             // works
$(Hello).replaceAll('img');              // breaks

$('img').replaceWith('.foo');            // breaks
$('.foo').replaceAll('img');             // works

$('img').replaceWith($('.foo'));         // works
$($('.foo')).replaceAll('img');          // works but is unnecessary
```

I've only explicitly tested the above example but I think the rules are equally valid for:

- before() & insertBefore()
- prepend() & prependTo()
- append() & appendTo()
- after() & insertAfter()

What is the general rule I am seeing here? I'd rather not guess and check each time I encounter a situation like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand here. The method names are self-explanatory.

Comment: @undefined for example, I can generalize the rules for the jQuery method: $() accepts 1. A string containing an existing element, class, or id  2. A string containing an element made on the fly. So can you give me a general set of rules which apply to all the methods I listed in the original question, or do they all have unique rules for the parameters they accept and I just have to memorize them.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, you've helped me before :) I'm looking for a general set of rules for what parameters these methods accept, not so much which method should be used in a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a general set of rules for what parameters these methods accept

Ahem... Extracted from jQuery documentation :

**[`.replaceWith(newContent)`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)**
`newContent` : htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery

**[`.replaceWith(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)**
`function` : Function

**[`.replaceAll(target)`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/)**
`target` : Selector or jQuery or Array or Element

**[`.before(content\[, content\])`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)**
**[`.after(content\[, content\])`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**
**[`.prepend(content\[, content\])`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)**
**[`.append(content\[, content\])`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**
`content` : htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery

**[`.insertBefore(target)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)**
**[`.insertAfter(target)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)**
**[`.prependTo(target)`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)**
**[`.appendTo(target)`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)**
`target` : Selector or htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery